# Unexpected Token Error when using array items as keys in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

In Chrome, the following JavaScript code throws an Unexpected Token error:

```
var somearray = ["foo","bar"];
var someassoc = {somearray[0]:somearray[1]};
```

The error thrown:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

When instead I would expect that it should make an object with a key of `somearray[0]` and an item of `somearray[1]` for that key.

So, why is this happening? An `Unexpected Token` normally means that a bracket has been misplaced somewhere, etc, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, when declaring an object, the key name should be always a simple string, for example:

```
var object = {'key': 'Hello World'};
```

However, if you would like to use a key name that is dynamic, like somearray[0], all you need to do is declare someassoc as an object:

```
var someassoc = {};
```

And then, set up a key-value combination, by doing:

```
someassoc.key = 'Hello World';
```

OR

```
someassoc['key'] = 'Hello World';
```

Which in your case will be:

```
someassoc[somearray[0]] = somearray[1];
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 7):

The key for the JS object literal must be either a static key, or an expression enclosed in `[]` (requires ES2015 support).

The problem with your code is that the `somearray[0]` key is invalid.

So if you need a ES5 way you rewrite it as

```
var somearray = ["foo","bar"];
var someassoc = {};
someassoc[somearray[0]] = somearray[1];
```

and for ES2015 you use

```
var somearray = ["foo","bar"];
var someassoc = { [somearray[0]]: somearray[1]};
```

Relevant parts of the standard:

- [12.2.6 Object Initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer)
- [12.2.6.3 Static Semantics: Contains](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-static-semantics-contains)
- [11.6.1 Identifier Names](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifier-names)

In short: the key must be a valid identifier.